# how to ensure that private constructor loads before accessing static member?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I ensure that when someone makes the following call, that the private constructor is executed?

```
var rc = CrmSecureConfiguration.RestCRMClientConfiguration;
```

Here's the implementation:

```
public class CrmSecureConfiguration
{
    private CrmSecureConfiguration()
    {
        var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

        RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMOrganizationName = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMOrganizationName"].Value;
        RestCRMClientConfiguration.UserName = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceUserName"].Value;
        RestCRMClientConfiguration.Password = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServicePassword"].Value;
        RestCRMClientConfiguration.Domain = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceDomain"].Value;
        RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMWebServiceBaseUrl = $"{configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceBaseUrl"].Value}/{RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMOrganizationName}/api/data/v8.1/";

    }
    public static RestCRMClientConfiguration RestCRMClientConfiguration { get; private set; }
}
```

For some reason, the current behavior is such that the private constructor is not executed at all.

Comment: Well why would you *expect* the constructor to be called? You haven't shown anything calling it...

Comment: You can try with static constructor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Comment: I would suggest to think about overall design, not this technical detail.

Comment: I agree with Divisadero. Consider using dependency injection and/or a provider interface rather than having this class be responsible for hydrating its own values. Then you can easily unit test classes that depend on these settings: you can set the values for each test according to the behaviors you're trying to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton pattern:

```
public class CrmSecureConfiguration
{
   private static CrmSecureConfigurationinstance;

   private CrmSecureConfiguration() {
      var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

      RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMOrganizationName = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMOrganizationName"].Value;
      RestCRMClientConfiguration.UserName = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceUserName"].Value;
      RestCRMClientConfiguration.Password = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServicePassword"].Value;
      RestCRMClientConfiguration.Domain = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceDomain"].Value;
      RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMWebServiceBaseUrl = $"{configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceBaseUrl"].Value}/{RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMOrganizationName}/api/data/v8.1/";
   }

   public static CrmSecureConfiguration Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new CrmSecureConfiguration();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }

   public RestCRMClientConfiguration RestCRMClientConfiguration { get; private set; }
}
```

Then client:

```
var rc = CrmSecureConfiguration.Instance.RestCRMClientConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that without creating an instance. Perhaps you want a static constructor instead?

```
static CrmSecureConfiguration()
{
    var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

    RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMOrganizationName = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMOrganizationName"].Value;
    RestCRMClientConfiguration.UserName = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceUserName"].Value;
    RestCRMClientConfiguration.Password = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServicePassword"].Value;
    RestCRMClientConfiguration.Domain = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceDomain"].Value;
    RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMWebServiceBaseUrl = $"{configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["CRMWebService"].Parameters["CRMWebServiceBaseUrl"].Value}/{RestCRMClientConfiguration.CRMOrganizationName}/api/data/v8.1/";

}
```